# how many distinct variables are represented in each group?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame such as this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c('123','124','125','126'),
  Group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  V1 = c(1,2,1,0),
  V2 = c(0,0,1,0),
  V3 = c(1,1,0,3))
```

which returns:

```
    ID Group V1 V2 V3
1 123     A  1  0  1
2 124     A  2  0  1
3 125     B  1  1  0
4 126     B  0  0  3
```

and I would like to return a table that indicates if a variable is represented in the group or not:

```
Group V1 V2 V3
A     1  0  1
B     1  1  1
```

In order to count the number of distinct variables in each group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(V1:V3), funs(as.integer(any(. > 0))))
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
   Group    V1    V2    V3
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      A     1     0     1
2      B     1     1     1
```

Comment: For whenever `summarise_each` is finally removed, `df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise_at(vars(V1:V3), funs(as.integer(any(. > 0))))` (or get rid of the `> 0` if you like)

Comment: I guess you duped a  similar question posted by user

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
table <- df[, .(sum(V1) > 0, sum(V2) > 0, sum(V3) > 0), Group]
table
   Group   V1    V2   V3
1:     A TRUE FALSE TRUE
2:     B TRUE  TRUE TRUE

table[, lapply(.SD, as.integer), Group, .SD=2:4]

   Group V1 V2 V3
1:     A  1  0  1
2:     B  1  1  1
```